# List container metadata from non-Keystone Swift

Tags: openstack-swift, jclouds, ceph, radosgw

This code makes *GET* request to RadosGW (I don't use Keystone)

```
String srcEndpoint = "http://myhost/auth/v1.0";
SwiftApi api = ContextBuilder.newBuilder(PROVIDER).endpoint(srcEndpoint)
                .credentials(srcIdentity, srcCredential).buildApi(SwiftApi.class);
```

If `PROVIDER` is **openstack-swift** my code throws

```
org.jclouds.http.HttpResponseException: command: POST http://myhost/auth/v1.0/tokens HTTP/1.1 failed with response: HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed; content: [{"Code":"MethodNotAllowed"}]
```

If `PROVIDER` is **swift** my code throws

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) No implementation for org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi was bound.
  while locating org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi
```

---

My dependencies are

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>swift</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>openstack-swift</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

How can I list all containers with all their metadata, without downloading the list of blobs it contains?

What's the difference between **swift** and **openstack-swift**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference is that *swift* supports v1 auth and *openstack-swift* supports v2 auth. Unfortunately, *swift* is also deprecated and no longer maintained.

The reason you are getting that error is because `SwiftApi` is specific to the *openstack-swift* API implementation. Despite the heroic efforts that jclouds makes to abstract away all the implementation details, it's not perfect. The *swift* API implementation returns `SwiftClient`, which extends [`CommonSwiftClient`](https://github.com/jclouds/legacy-jclouds/blob/master/apis/swift/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/swift/CommonSwiftClient.java) (where all the interesting methods are defined).

Also, as you may have guessed, `SwiftClient` is in a different package. So be sure to include `package org.jclouds.openstack.swift;` (no ".v1")

You can list all containers with their metadata by calling `listContainers(ListContainerOptions... options)` on your `SwiftClient` instance. This will return `Set<ContainerMetadata>`.

Comment: I made it work (y) But I still need to list container names and then query additional data for each container. Can I get all containers with their metadata with one request?

Comment: Did the listContainers() method not work? You can also call BlobStore.list().

Comment: RadosGW returns only `name`, `count` and `bytes` for both those methods

Comment: Ohhh... I thought you were actually using Swift. All bets are off when you're talking to a Swift-like API on a gateway backed by a block store. That's just too many layers of translation going on. Ceph is great choice for a cost-effective distributed block storage cluster. But if you need object storage, it's best to go with the genuine article: Swift. Despite what many people think, Ceph and Swift are not competitors. In fact, they complement each other quite elegantly in a large-scale infrastructure. Email me and I'll be happy to get you up and running: adam@swiftstack.com